# Missing Folders from PHP Project in Hudson Output 

Tags: php, svn, hudson

I got a problem while running a PHP project in Hudson Continuous Integration server.  After building the PHP project, I had checked archived build output and there were some folders missing.  I checked the SVN repository and all of the folders missing in Hudson's output were present in the SVN repository.  Can somebody explain why this happened?

### Steps in detail

1. I had selected `free style build`
2. Configured SCM. I am using SVN as source code repository
3. From build step I haven't invoked `ant` or `phing`
4. Checked and configured archive artifact option for PHP

When I try to invoke `ant` or `phing`, it returns with an error message saying that there is no `build.xml` file in workspace.

I want to know about the relation between build.xml file and PHP project build in Hudson?

Comment: You have to provide us a little more details... So far I can't tell anything. How did you configure your project in Hudson?

Comment: @renju chandran: you should be able to edit your question in order to add more details

Answer (score 0):

`Ant` and `Phing` requires a `build.xml` that defines the rules and actions that is executed when Hudson is "building" the project. For a PHP project this can be unit tests (Using PHPUnit), reports on styling/syntax (PHP_Codesniffer) or making PHPDoc.

[Template for Jenkins Jobs for PHP Projects](http://jenkins-php.org/) has example on how to set up Ant in Jenkins (almost the same as Hudson) with the required `build.xml` and some example targets.

Have a look at the console output about the SVN issue. Also take a look at the workspace in Hudson.